# Ionic Modal Slider issue: could not find a corresponding element with delegate-handle= on $emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic application that has multiple angular controllers. One of the controllers is LoginCtrl and another is RegisterCtrl. The issue im having is that I call a $emit within Login Ctrl to open a modal with a slider from within the RegisterCtrl:

**Modal Template HTML**

```
<!-- A very cut down version of my code -->
<ion-content class="register-wrapper">
    <ion-slide-box delegate-handle="registerSlider" show-pager="false">
        <ion-slide class="padding">
            Slide 1
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide class="padding">
            Slide 2
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide class="padding">
            Slide 3
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>

</ion-content>
```

**LoginCrtl**

```
$rootScope.$emit("showRegisterPopup", {data:'somedata'});
```

**RegisterCrtl**

```
// This is a cut down version of the code
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/register-form1.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.registerModalSlider = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('registerSlider');
    $scope.registerModalSlider.enableSlide(false);
});

$rootScope.$on("showRegisterPopup", function(emitEvent, somedata){
    if ($scope.registerModalSlider){
        $timeout(function({
            $scope.registerModalSlider.slide(2);
        },200);
    }
    rc.showRegister();
});
```

The issue I get is when I call the .slide() function of the slider it is not sliding to the page specified and i get the following error:

```
Delegate for handle "registerSlider" could not find a corresponding element with delegate-handle="registerSlider"! slide() was not called!
Possible cause: If you are calling slide() immediately, and your element with delegate-handle="registerSlider" is a child of your controller, then your element may not be compiled yet. Put a $timeout around your call to slide() and try again.
```

As you can see I have set the delegate-handle in the HTML and I already have the .slide() call within a timeout and that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet on JSFiddle that reproduces the issue? How controllers are applied to templates?

Comment: I know its hard for you guys to debug if you dont have a working example but I cant seem to reproduce the issue inside a jsfiddle. It looks like it could be something to do with the template being loaded from a file?

Comment: In that case information about the way controllers are initialized might help. Also, the way you open modal seems suboptimal. I'd create a service that exposes a function to open registration modal and accepts slide index, expose index on $scope and then bind it to slide using active-slide attribute (check the docs). I have a feeling this will resolve the issue.

Comment: The LoginCtrl is initialised on the body of the index.html file and the Register Controller is initialised in a div on the body that wraps around the whole of the content. Are you able to provide some example code of what you mean by creating a service for it? Whats the benefit of using a service to open the modal as appose to using a controller?

Comment: [Here's a demo plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kn1V5sl4Pk7BNABATHjF?p=preview). My previous experience shows that moving modals into separate services or states is easier to support and reason about. It also decouples business logic from view, becuase no $scope events are used.

Comment: Okay so I tried what you suggested moving the popup functionality into a service (this does make sense to keep the code within its own service) however I am still getting the same warning as per my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the "active-slide" attribute on the slider. This basically takes an integer that you update to whatever index of the slide you want to see.

In view:

```
<ion-slide-box delegate-handle="registerSlider" show-pager="false" active-slide="currentSlide">
</ion-slide-box>
```

In controller:

```
//Instead of this:
if ($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('registerSlider')){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('registerSlider').slide(2);
}

// Do this...
$scope.currentStep = 2;
```

Comment: This was driving me nuts, thanks for this answer @Glen Robson

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resoved in this way in the following [github issues](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1865)

> So what the member did was he added a delegateHandle attribute in the
>   scope to for the way to be interplolated.

You can use a **universal-directive** as used in the following [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/imAjt) and apply the following modifications to it

```
Like this:

scope: {
        //
        delegateHandle: '@'
      }
```

Then by changing the following line in your code

```
`$scope.registerModalSlider = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('registerSlider',$attr.delegateHandle);
```

`to

```
$scope.registerModalSlider = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('registerSlider',$scope.delegateHandle);
```

So now the `delegates will be interpolated` and you can also access the handles correctly.

also as suggested by  [@mikesurowiec](https://github.com/mikesurowiec) you can add the following directive to use a `random generated delegate handle`

```
angular.module('app').directive('randomDelegateHandle', [function () {
  return {
    priority: 1000,
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        tAttrs.$set('delegateHandle', Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));
        return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {}
    }
};

}]);
```

or you can also follow the other solution mention in the GitHub Issues.

Hope this might help a bit.

*Full attribution goes to the github issues and the authors mentioned above*